# Exact match specific word with RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up my .htaccess files with some RewriteRules, but unfortunatly I got stuck. I've found a lot of topics on this, but none mentioning my specific issue.
I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^en/contact /contact.php?lang=en&slug=ok [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact /en/contact [L,R=301]
```

Purpose is to force the lang as a first parameter in the url if not set.
So: www.example.com/contact should be redirected (301) to www.example.com/en/contact which then again loads the content from /contact.php?lang=en&slug=ok

The problem I have is that I end up in a loop as /contact.php?lang=en&slug=ok gets loaded and is parsed by *RewriteRule ^contact /en/contact [L,R=301]* again.

How can I adapt this rule so it is **only** triggered for **/contact** and  not for /contact.php or /en/contact or /contactme or any other url that contains *contact*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 301 redirect rule is causing the infinite loop  as it matches the destination path of your first rule. What is happening is that when you request `/en/contact` your first rule rewrites it to `/contact.php?lang=en&slug=ok` and then ,your second rule matches the same uri and redirects it to `/en/contact` .

To fix this, You can either use END flag in your RewriteRule or use `THE_REQUEST` condition .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/contact /contact.php?lang=en&slug=ok [L,NC,END]
RewriteRule ^contact /en/contact [L,R=301]
```

Note : `END` flag works only on apache versions above `2.4` if your server version is less then 2.4 you could use a `% {THE_REQUEST}` condition to terminate the redirect loop

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/contact /contact.php?lang=en&slug=ok [L,NC]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /contact
 RewriteRule ^contact /en/contact [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these redirects.

Comment: Thank you, the END flag solution works great. I think an syntax, flag or option to identify a string as EXACT would still be a great add-on nevertheless.